# Removing heading level from table of contents

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have 3 levels of headings in my document (1 - Heading, 1.1 Heading, 1.1.1 Heading)

I want to only show the upper 2 levels (1 & 1.1) in my table of contents - is there a way to remove the 1.1.1 headings?

I do not want to have to delete them each time i need to refresh the TOC

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for this problem is to insert a new custom TOC and in General>show level>2

[image: Example]